# Network interface restarting too often on Mint 18

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, thinkpad

I work on a remote server via ssh and I've noticed that Vim sometimes freezed for 5-10 seconds.

ifconfig:

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:b5:93:fe  
          inet addr:10.30.10.230  Bcast:10.30.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f995:dba3:a12d:bc16/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7745442 errors:8 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:6
          TX packets:723918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1036026983 (1.0 GB)  TX bytes:85008484 (85.0 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f0600000-f0620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:99543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:99543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:13269150 (13.2 MB)  TX bytes:13269150 (13.2 MB)
```

Dmesg shows that interface often ups and downs for no reason for me (there are many more such lines in the output):

```
[544981.654197] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[545084.381711] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Down
```

uname -a:

```
Linux farit-PC 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's a Thinkpad T440s.

How can I be sure that it is not connected with Mint or ThinkPad itself?
I've already made a ticket to our IT team for checking the network, but would like to check my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a very weird answer, but looks like that was some occasional error.

I did nothing with FlowControl and everything works ok now. At least week has passed and there were no problems.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that because you don't have flow control like it says in your Dmesg, your nic is dropping packets when other things require the network. If the network becomes overloaded it will start dropping packets if there is no flow control. It could also be that something overloading your nic, you could try finding this out, by keeping netstat open and monitoring to see if something is just opening connections continously.

This could also be a sign that your nic is dying or is faulty, which the only way to correct is getting a new one and this won't usually be determined until you have exausted all steps to correct or identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: How can I check the overload case? Could it be smth in logs or journals?

Comment: Also, how can I turn on the Flow control? Will it help?

Comment: @cheetahfm take a look at http://www.tecmint.com/20-netstat-commands-for-linux-network-management/     that link will show you all the different flags you can use with netstat to help see what your network is doing

Answer (score 0):

Your `dmesg` output shows a *most likely* cause of error: it states:

> Flow Control: None

[Flow control (on Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_(data)) is:

> the process of managing the rate of data transmission between two nodes to prevent a fast sender from overwhelming a slow receiver.

This is strange, because the module `e1000e` (**not** the module *e1000* as I initially thought you had) has [FlowControl enabled by default](https://gist.github.com/pklaus/319367). So the only thing I can think of is that you have `autonegotiation` disabled. Try issuing, as sudo, the follwoing command:

```
ethtool -A enp0s25 autoneg on rx on
```

reload the module,

```
modprobe -r e1000e
modprobe e1000e
```

(if the first command does not work, then try it as follows:

```
ip link set dev enp0s25 down
modprobe -r e10000e
modprobe e1000e
ip link set dev enp0s25 up
```

it should work now), and see whether you still encounter the same problem. If this fixes your problem, then you can perform the `ethtool` automatically at boot by creating the file `/etc/modprobe.d/e1000e.conf` with the following unique line:

```
post-install e1000e ethtool -A enp0s? autoneg on rx on
```

Comment: you are correct, removed my comment about that. And you are correct the easiest way to reload a module is to restart the system.

Comment: Is "e1000" interface name?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I've run the command, restarted, but the dmesg shows "e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None". The file was created and it's contents are as in command, but that did not affect the FlowControl.

Comment: @cheetahfm Pls see my updated answer.